# overloaded method value ofDim with alternatives in scala

Tags: java, arrays, scala

```
def accessRecord(filePath: String, recordSize: Long, offset: Long): Int = {
     val fs = FileSystem.get(SparkHadoopUtil.get.conf)
     val stream = fs.open(new Path(filePath))
     val bytes = Array.ofDim[Byte](recordSize)
     stream.readFully(offset, bytes)
     stream.close()
     bytes.length
     }
```

In the above code the recordSize variable is passed as a parameter which receive the value from one of the function below with the data type as Long. So it gives error which says

```
error: overloaded method value ofDim with alternatives:
  (n1: Int,n2: Int,n3: Int,n4: Int,n5: Int)(implicit evidence$7: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Byte])Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Byte]]]]] <and>
  (n1: Int,n2: Int,n3: Int,n4: Int)(implicit evidence$6: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Byte])Array[Array[Array[Array[Byte]]]] <and>
  (n1: Int,n2: Int,n3: Int)(implicit evidence$5: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Byte])Array[Array[Array[Byte]]] <and>
  (n1: Int,n2: Int)(implicit evidence$4: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Byte])Array[Array[Byte]] <and>
  (n1: Int)(implicit evidence$3: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Byte])Array[Byte]
 cannot be applied to (Long)
           val bytes = Array.ofDim[Byte](recordSize)
                                  ^
```

Can some one tell me why am i facing this error?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum length of an array is controlled by the fixed integer length of the array. That is why `ofDim` takes `Int` arguments, however you are passing a `Long` in `recordSize` (that is the source and meaning of the error). To resolve it, you could call `Long.toInt` like

```
val bytes = Array.ofDim[Byte](recordSize.toInt)
```

or change `recordSize` to an `Int`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply and help @Elliott Frisch

Answer (score 1):

Because `Array.ofDim[A](size: Int)` does not expect a `Long`.

In general, arrays on JVM are always indexed by 32-bit integers, and it probably won't change, because it's now impossible to replace the return type of `.length` by `Long` without breaking everything.

Comment: Thank you so much..@ Andrey

Comment: @DishaPurohit I'm now googling around trying to find a standard solution for arrays with more than 2 billion entries. Do you really have more than 2^31 entries, or is it just an integer size inconveniently stored as `Long`? I mean... a *single* record larger than 2GB?

Comment: Currently i don't have a record which is larger than 2GB. But it would be great if we are able to derive solution for such situation as well.